# Jenkins: Running Scanner for MSBuild under Local System or Network Service account is not supported

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I want to integrate SonarQube with a Jenkins project (ASP.NET project). I am trying to build a Jenkins job containing a build step for "SonarScanner for MSBuild " begin/end analysis. But I get the following error:

"**Running the Scanner for MSBuild under Local System or Network Service account is not supported. Please, use a local or domain user account instead.**"

I even tried removing the "SonarScanner for MSBuild " begin/end analysis steps and manually executing Windows batch commands (which is working fine outside of Jenkins). But through Jenkins, I am getting the same error for the batch commands as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem. I did the following: Services > Jenkins > Right Click - Properties > Log On tab > Changing it from 'Local System Account' to 'This Account'.