# Execution of SonarScanner for MSBuild failed?

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

[I have used this link also, but didnt work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950822/jenkins-running-scanner-for-msbuild-under-local-system-or-network-service-accou)

I am trying to build my project using jenkins which has sonarqube integrated, but unfortunately, it is giving me this error.

[image: Jenkins console output when i build my c-sharp project]

I am using MSBuild. And the configuration for the project as below.

[image: MSBuild configuration error]

please help, as i am stuck in this for hours.

Thanks.

P.S i am using c# and MSBuild as sonar scanner. Here are the parameters i have specified after downlaoding the MSBuild sonarscanner plugins.

[image: SOnarqube configuration for MSBuild]

Comment: "...use a local or domain user account instead." Is Jenkins running in IIS? Are you using Local System or Network Service as the identity for the application pool?

Comment: @Crowcoder jenkins running in own pc, i mean localhost, i am the admin.

Comment: I think I meant SonarQube. Is that running in IIS?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what do you mean by IIS ? Sonarqube too running in my pc only (admin rights), localhost.

Comment: I'm no expert with Jenkins nor sonarqube but at it looks to me like it's running as a website. Internet Information Services (IIS) is the Microsoft web server. Applications in IIS run as a process with application pools. App pools run as an identity. It looks to me like you need to change that identity to a real account.